# Why there is little report about Huawei's launch of Mate 60 Pro phone?

Tags: united-states, china, media, technology

Last week Chinese social media went viral about Huawei's launch of Mate 60 Pro phone (Aug 29). To the Chinese people, this is just another example of what doesn’t kill you makes you stronger.

But I find there is little report about it in English-language media. Actually, I only find 2 reports,

1. ["New phone sparks worry China has found a way around U.S. tech limits"](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2023/09/02/huawei-raimondo-phone-chip-sanctions/) from Washington Post
2. [China chip stocks rally after Huawei's low-key launch of new Mate 60 Pro phone](https://www.reuters.com/technology/chip-stocks-rally-after-huaweis-low-key-launch-new-mate-60-pro-phone-2023-08-30/) from Reuters

Reading these two articles you definitely won't find the excitement the Chinese people have about Mate 60.

One reason I see from time to time is they don't report the news their readers know little of, or have little interest in. But Huawei seems not to fit in this category. So why there is so little report?

--- update ---

10 days after the launch, nytimes has its first report https://cn.nytimes.com/business/20230907/huawei-phone-us-china-raimondo/dual/

But I have yet to see BCC reports it. BBC covers a lot of news about China and Huawei(timely reporting), but strangely it does not report Mate 60 yet.

PS, [Press Briefing by Press Secretary Karine Jean-Pierre and National Security Advisor Jake Sullivan](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2023/09/05/press-briefing-by-press-secretary-karine-jean-pierre-and-national-security-advisor-jake-sullivan-6/) he said,

> And for my — from my perspective though, what it tells us, regardless,
> is that the United States should continue on its course of a “small
> yard, high fence” set of technology restrictions focused narrowly on
> national security concerns ...

Comment: There are many close reasons that apply here: **Lack of focus**, as you're asking about "western media" which actually includes hundreds of publications in many different countries, who all have different interests and opinions regarding Huawei and China. **Not about political processes**, as you are asking about tech journalism (which may have political implications but isn't directly political). And finally **promoting a specific cause**, as you don't seem to be interested in why "western media" might not cover the launch and instead seem to want to argue that it's because of "sour grapes".

Comment: Well, I have to reword my question then. I am not promoting a specific cause like sour grapes otherwise I won't ask this question.  As for the western media, I know there is no such thing as western media. So do I call them English media ?

Comment: But before I asked the question I already suspected this question may not belong to the politics category.

Comment: A better question might be: Was the U.S. government surprised about the Huawei breakthrough, how much time did the U.S. government or think-tank expect China to take to produce a 7nm chip?

Comment: Feel free to reword the question! :) As for focus, English-language media makes sense, as the publications are more likely to be familiar to the people on this site and can also be cited without translation.But I don't think that fixes the lack of focus. Take your examples: Neither *Reuters*, nor the *Washington Post* are known to be excited. And both articles acknowledge the achievement these new chips would present. But they don't do hype, instead maintaing a matter-of-fact tone in all their reporting. Again, different publications do things differently and should not be lumped together.

Comment: @Sayaman That would indeed be a good question and probably get at the heart of the issue. It also fixes the topicality problem as it is clearly about political actors.

Comment: @Sayaman but I would rather ask that as another question. For this particular question I just want to know why so little coverage.

Comment: @xyldke thanks for all the advice and comments. I reword my question. But I only want to why so little coverage on this question so I didn't reword as Sayaman suggested.

Comment: There is nothing political about a new phone being released.

Comment: @Philipp Normally I would agree with that but not for this phone. I think Bloomberg's report [Huawei Teardown Reveals China Chip Breakthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFNqltF7dnI) shared my point.

Comment: The expectation that major news outlets should have articles about new smartphones, particularly within days of their release and when the device is not available in most of the target audience's market, seems questionable. For instance, the *New York Times* has just one article about the Galaxy S23 series, written about three weeks after its announcement, and just two or three articles about the iPhone 14 series (which has been out for almost a year). I would look to technical publications for articles about smartphones.

Comment: South China Morning Post is not an independent news source.  It's propaganda.

Comment: @Philipp,  I agree with Qiulang,  This phone which negates U.S. sanctions and introduced while the American Labor Secretary was visiting China is all about Politics.

Comment: @Obie2.0 check [Press Briefing by Press Secretary Karine Jean-Pierre and National Security Advisor Jake Sullivan](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2023/09/05/press-briefing-by-press-secretary-karine-jean-pierre-and-national-security-advisor-jake-sullivan-6/)

Comment: @JMS In the attempt to show the political relevance of the launch, we have now found multiple English-language, western sources that talk about it (Washington Post, Reuters, Bloomberg). I also found an article by the Guardian. I'm sure if you also look at reporting on chip production (which is the politically interesting part of this phone), you'll find a few more. So it becomes unclear what is considered an acceptable level of reporting according to the question and why it is unusual (and thus requiring an explanation) that this level is not reached.

Comment: @xyldke to me is simple, BBC. BBC is the media I would like to see( not CNN) and BBC covers a lot of news about China and Huawei, but strangely this time no report from it yet.

Comment: @xyldke  Are you claiming the South China Morning Post is not propaganda?  Western sources covering the Mate 60's Pro launch even calling it an achievement doesn't negate the previous fact nor the strange way the Mate 60 pro was lunched.    We know almost nothing about the chip, not even the name from the manufactures at launch.  All our information came from consumers who purchased the phone originally.   The Manufactures are oddly silent on this national prestige achievement, no press conference, no launch event,  no product spec?   South China Morning Post's claims otherwise are meaningless

Comment: @JMS I feel like the question needs editing, partly to improve the grammar and make it more structured, but mostly to clarify the political connection (i.e. the fact that Huawei have bypassed US sanctions by using Chinese-manufactured chips). I don't have the time to do so right now, but perhaps you'd consider doing it?

Comment: Not sure how you came to this conclusion. It seems to be all over the business news: Bloomberg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFNqltF7dnI etc. You yourself linked to CNN's coverage in answering another Q. According to Chinese vloggers, this China-only device was not advertised before launch, so the slight delay in Western press coverage is entirely reasonable IMHO.

Comment: @Fizz this is very easy to come to this conclusion, whenver something "bad" happens CNN/BBC/WSJ report immedaitely. For exmaple WSJ reported today "China Bans iPhone Use for Government Officials at Work", which isn't remotely reported  in China at all and I doubt it is the case. But for Huawei's breakthough, almost 10 days later, even after whitehouse response, CNN/BBC have yet to report it.

Comment: Because I'm pretty sure the ban did not require teardown in a specialized lab of any device to unravel. According to Reuters, Huawei refused to answer any [of their] Qs about the Mate 60.

Comment: I didn't link to CNN (and I don't like CNN at all) I linked NYTimes's China version because its original version is not free. I doubt you even read it.

Comment: So they don't even verify the ban is true or not. Come on it is WSJ not Foxs news

Comment: My bad on that. Anyhow CNN also covered the Sulllivan press conf https://edition.cnn.com/2023/09/06/tech/huawei-mate-60-pro-phone/index.html and also said Huawei didn't answer any of their Qs. So you're not the only Chinese who dislikes CNN...

Answer (score 1):

> This is still about two generations behind chips made for global
> leaders

([source](https://asia.nikkei.com/Business/Tech/Semiconductors/Huawei-to-restart-5G-mobile-chip-output-as-early-as-this-year#:%7E:text=Huawei%2C%20a%20onetime%20smartphone%20powerhouse,the%20matter%20told%20Nikkei%20Asia)). Enough to explain the differences between interpreting the importance of this phone by mass media in China (that is likely to be positively biased) and USA, EU (that is more likely to be negatively biased). It is a step ahead but not so that China managed to leave "collective West" in the dust on chip technology.

Comment: This thing is I never heard of nikkei before. Do you? Doesn't that just confirm my question that no western media report it?

Comment: @Quilang Nikkei is one of the largest financial newspapers in the world,  if not *the* largest. It's hardly obscure.

Comment: @PhillS I checked its Japanese name so I know it just don't know its English name.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it has to do with the fact that Huawei was silent about how they developed their chips, so they're waiting to know the full facts of the matter before publishing an article on how China has been able to evade U.S. sanctions, but this is of course only speculations.

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2023-09-04/look-inside-huawei-mate-60-pro-phone-powered-by-made-in-china-chip

> The company’s Mate 60 Pro is powered by SMIC’s 7nm chips, according to
> analysis that TechInsights

Bloomberg had to confirm that it was using a 7nm process after TechInsights did a teardown of the phone. Before that, people could only speculate on how China was able to produce these chips. Some speculated they came from older inventories that came from TSMC. They had to fact check before publishing anything.

Comment: Check this Bloomberg's report [Huawei Teardown Reveals China Chip Breakthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFNqltF7dnI) too.